# Setting nan to rows in pandas dataframe based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

Using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = pd.read_csv('file.csv', na_values=['-9999.0'], decimal=',')
a.index = pd.to_datetime(a[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute']])
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

The dataframe is something like:

```
Index               A    B       C      D
2016-07-20 18:00:00 9   4.0     NaN    2
2016-07-20 19:00:00 9   2.64    0.0    3
2016-07-20 20:00:00 12  2.59    0.0    1
2016-07-20 21:00:00 9   4.0     NaN    2
```

The main objective is to set np.nan to the entire row if the value on A column is 9 and on D column is 2 at the same time, for exemple:

Output expectation

```
Index               A    B       C      D
2016-07-20 18:00:00 NaN NaN     NaN    NaN
2016-07-20 19:00:00 9   2.64    0.0     3
2016-07-20 20:00:00 12  2.59    0.0     2
2016-07-20 21:00:00 NaN NaN     NaN    NaN
```

Would be thankful if someone could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
This is the opposite of @Jezrael's `mask` solution.

```
a.where(a.A.ne(9) | a.D.ne(2))

                        A     B    C    D
Index                                    
2016-07-20 18:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-07-20 19:00:00   9.0  2.64  0.0  3.0
2016-07-20 20:00:00  12.0  2.59  0.0  1.0
2016-07-20 21:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.DataFrame.reindex`

```
a[a.A.ne(9) | a.D.ne(2)].reindex(a.index)

                        A     B    C    D
Index                                    
2016-07-20 18:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-07-20 19:00:00   9.0  2.64  0.0  3.0
2016-07-20 20:00:00  12.0  2.59  0.0  1.0
2016-07-20 21:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df.A.eq(9) & df.D.eq(2)] = [np.nan] * len(df.columns)
```

Demo:

```
In [158]: df
Out[158]:
                      A     B    C  D
Index
2016-07-20 18:00:00   9  4.00  NaN  2
2016-07-20 19:00:00   9  2.64  0.0  3
2016-07-20 20:00:00  12  2.59  0.0  1
2016-07-20 21:00:00   9  4.00  NaN  2

In [159]: df.loc[df.A.eq(9) & df.D.eq(2)] = [np.nan] * len(df.columns)

In [160]: df
Out[160]:
                        A     B    C    D
Index
2016-07-20 18:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-07-20 19:00:00   9.0  2.64  0.0  3.0
2016-07-20 20:00:00  12.0  2.59  0.0  1.0
2016-07-20 21:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

alternatively we can use [DataFrame.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method:

```
In [174]: df = df.where(~(df.A.eq(9) & df.D.eq(2)))

In [175]: df
Out[175]:
                        A     B    C    D
Index
2016-07-20 18:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-07-20 19:00:00   9.0  2.64  0.0  3.0
2016-07-20 20:00:00  12.0  2.59  0.0  1.0
2016-07-20 21:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value` for first solution :(

Comment: @jezrael, can you provide a sample data set to reproduce this error?

Comment: @jezrael, i can't reproduce it

Comment: @jezrael, pandas: 0.20.1

Comment: my is `pandas: 0.20.3` - maybe in future version it failed

Comment: is possible upgrade?

Comment: @jezrael, i would expect that such basic stuff like `df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), columns=list('abc'));df.iloc[0] = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]` would work in newer versions as well...

Comment: @jezrael, i will upgrade as soon as it's available via Anaconda for my platform...

Comment: Hmmm, ok. After change answer I can add your solution to timings. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), which create `NaN`s by default:

```
df = a.mask((a['A'] == 9) & (a['D'] == 2))
print (df)
                        A     B    C    D
Index                                    
2016-07-20 18:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-07-20 19:00:00   9.0  2.64  0.0  3.0
2016-07-20 20:00:00  12.0  2.59  0.0  1.0
2016-07-20 21:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with assign `NaN`:

```
a[(a['A'] == 9) & (a['D'] == 2)] = np.nan
print (a)
                        A     B    C    D
Index                                    
2016-07-20 18:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-07-20 19:00:00   9.0  2.64  0.0  3.0
2016-07-20 20:00:00  12.0  2.59  0.0  1.0
2016-07-20 21:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrst'.upper())

a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan,2,9], size=(N,20)), columns=L)
```

---

```
#jez2
In [256]: %timeit a[(a['A'] == 9) & (a['D'] == 2)] = np.nan
10 loops, best of 3: 25.8 ms per loop

#jez2upr
In [257]: %timeit a.loc[(a['A'] == 9) & (a['D'] == 2)] = np.nan
10 loops, best of 3: 27.6 ms per loop

#Wen
In [258]: %timeit a.mul(np.where((a.A==9)&(a.D==2),np.nan,1),0)
10 loops, best of 3: 90.5 ms per loop

#jez1
In [259]: %timeit a.mask((a['A'] == 9) & (a['D'] == 2))
1 loop, best of 3: 316 ms per loop

#maxu2
In [260]: %timeit a.where(~(a.A.eq(9) & a.D.eq(2)))
1 loop, best of 3: 318 ms per loop

#pir1
In [261]: %timeit a.where(a.A.ne(9) | a.D.ne(2))
1 loop, best of 3: 316 ms per loop

#pir2
In [263]: %timeit a[a.A.ne(9) | a.D.ne(2)].reindex(a.index)
1 loop, best of 3: 355 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try using`.mul` after `np.where`

```
a=np.where((df2.A==9)&(df2.D==2),np.nan,1)
df2.mul(a,0)
#one line df.mul(np.where((df.A==9)&(df.D==2),np.nan,1))

                        A     B    C    D
Index                                    
2016-07-20 18:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-07-20 19:00:00   9.0  2.64  0.0  3.0
2016-07-20 20:00:00  12.0  2.59  0.0  1.0
2016-07-20 21:00:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: This is clever (-:

Comment: yes, indeed, it's a smart option! We can make a one-liner out of it: `df.mul(np.where((df.A==9)&(df.D==2),np.nan,1))`

Comment: @MaxU thank you ,  Yes, you are right online more neat ~